# How to get rid of empty space on the right of a container with floating items?

Tags: css

When I use floating itens inside a container, like:

**The Code (http://jsfiddle.net/tombrito/gx7kL330/7/):**

```css
.container {
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
}
.floating-box {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
  <div class="floating-box">Floating box</div>
</div>
```

...if I resize the window, I see that the `width: auto` of the container is not exactly the width of the contents:

[image]

There is some empty space on the right. Is there a way to make the container really be the width of the floating children, even when I resize it?

Comment: Try the answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18482505/having-the-floating-children-elements-determine-parent-width) but i think you'll struggle if you have more elements so that they wrap...

Comment: if you use bootstrap then it will be easy, or you can make a jquery function for it.

Comment: Basically...no. That's not the way the line box model works.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: @Stuart those answers won't work for more the one line of elements, unfortunately.

Comment: Indeed, as I said you'll struggle with multiple floated elements that wrap... You should really rethink what it is you're trying to achieve, there _will_ be an elegant way.

Comment: @Stuart it's a menu of box itens (box images). I can use other layouts if this don't work. But I really would like to use this one.

Comment: Must you have fixed widths on each item? Or can they be flexible?

Comment: @Stuart must be fixed, the images size width and height, all same size (say, 100x100 pixels).

Comment: In this case, can you not determine, and fix the width of the container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108567/discussion-between-tom-brito-and-stuart).

Answer (score 0):

You can using flexbox rules. ([source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/))

html:

```
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;

  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  line-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: No...not really you can't...even flexbox can't do that. It's not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: That will distribute the boxes in the space, but I really would like to make the container small to fit the content size. Anyway, interesting to know about this property... :)

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is an option, I would do something like this;

```
$('body').on('resize', function () { 
    var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.innerWidth,
        itemWidth = 150 + 20 + 6; //width + margin + border,
        count = Math.floor(width / itemWidth),
        containerWidth = itemWidth * count;

    $('.container').css('width', containerWidth + 'px'); 
});
```

// untested code warning